# Python code to encrypt and email PDF file using PyPDF2

Tags: python, python-2.x, csv, email, pdf

This is my first programming project with real world application.  It's purpose is to take a file from a directory, encrypt it with a predetermined password, and email to appropriate recipient.
ID Email and Password are found in a CSV file that I created EmailDict from. 
ID and Filename are parsed and dropped into FileDict.  Any feedback is valued and appreciated.

```
import os 
import re
import csv
import PyPDF2
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText 
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart


# Create a dictionary with the csv values for ID, Email and Password
EmailDict = dict()
with open('commissionrepemaillist.csv', 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader :
        REP = row[0]
        EMAIL = row[1]
        PASSWORD = row[2]
        EmailDict[REP] = EMAIL, PASSWORD

# create dictionary of IDs and Pdf Files
FileDict = dict()
path = "C:\\Apps\\CorVu\\DATA\\Reports\\Monthly Commission Reports\\Output\\pdcom1"  
for FILE in os.listdir(path):
    split = re.split("[_.]", FILE)
    ID = split[1]
    FileDict[ID] = FILE

# encrypt PDF files in FileDict based on ID and Password from EmailDict
for ID in FileDict:
    if ID in EmailDict:
        path = "C:\\Apps\\CorVu\\DATA\\Reports\\Monthly Commission Reports\\Output\\pdcom1\\"
        file = os.path.join(path + FileDict[ID])

        inputStream = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
        output = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
        output.appendPagesFromReader(inputStream)
        output.encrypt(EmailDict[ID][1])

        with open(file, 'wb') as outputStream:
            output.write(outputStream)  


    else : continue

# email encrypted pdf file to appropriate rep 

for ID in FileDict:
    path = "C:\\Apps\\CorVu\\DATA\\Reports\\Monthly Commission Reports\\Output\\pdcom1\\"
    file = os.path.join(path + FileDict[ID])
    with open(file, 'rb') as pdf :
        pdfAttachment = MIMEApplication(pdf.read(), _subtype = 'pdf')
        pdfAttachment.add_header('content-disposition', 'attachment', filename=('MonthlyPaidCommission_%s.pdf' % ID))
        text = MIMEText(
        """For Rep Number : %s 
        Please use the password previously emailed to open attached file.
        If you have any questions or need assistance please contact  me.
        Thank you""" % ID)
    msg = MIMEMultipart(_subparts = (text, pdfAttachment))   
    msg['SUBJECT'] = "Commission Report"
    msg['FROM'] = "me@gmail.com"
    msg['TO'] = EMAIL

    s = smtplib.SMTP("LOCALHOST:587")
    s.starttls()
    s.login('user', 'pwd')
    s.sendmail('me@123.com', EMAIL, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
```

Comment: I've fixed an indentation error for you in Rev 3. Please check your entire question to verify that your code has been posted as intended.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is easy enough to follow.  All of your `open()` calls are done using `with` blocks, which is a good habit.

Your variables — such as `REP` and `EmailDict` — are unconventionally named.  Use [`ALL_CAPS` for constants](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id30), and `lower_case` for variables.  Ironically, the one variable that should be a constant, `path`, is defined several times, and not written as a constant.

Speaking of `path`, you are misusing [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).  The whole point of the function is to ensure that the path delimiter is automatically inserted for you between the components.  So, you should write `os.path.join(path, FileDict[ID])` instead.  Also, use [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) to make your backslashes less cumbersome.

---

I doubt that there is any value in writing all of those encrypted versions of the files to disk.  You could just create a transient encrypted copy in memory, mail it off, and move on to the next recipient.  To accomplish that, you can write to a [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) object instead of a file.

The code to encrypt the PDF and compose the mail message feels like it could belong logically together.  I'd define a function for that:

```
def message_for(unencrypted_pdf_path, rep_id, email, password):
    """
    Creates a MIME message for a rep containing an encrypted version
    of the specified PDF.
    """
    buf = StringIO()
    …
    encrypted_pdf = buf.getvalue()

    text = MIMEText(… % rep_id)

    pdf_attachment = MIMEApplication(encrypted_pdf, _subtype='pdf')
    pdf_attachment.add_header('content-disposition', 'attachment', filename=('MonthlyPaidCommission_%s.pdf' % rep_id))

    msg = MIMEMultipart(_subparts=[text, pdf_attachment])
    msg['SUBJECT'] = 'Commission Report'
    msg['FROM'] = 'me'
    msg['TO'] = rep['EMAIL']
    return msg
```

---

Your code would be more expressive if you defined the dictionary entries "all at once" using a dict comprehension.  I would also avoid storing the e-mail and password as a tuple, since it makes you write more cryptic code like `EmailDict[ID][1]` later.

I think that you would be better off not defining `FileDict` at all.  Just process each directory entry as you encounter it.  You can even send multiple messages within the same SMTP connection.  Just make sure you keep a log of what was sent, in case something goes wrong.

```
PATH = r'C:\Apps\CorVu\DATA\Reports\Monthly Commission Reports\Output\pdcom1'

COLS = ['rep_id', 'email', 'password']
with open('commissionrepemaillist.csv', 'r') as infile:
    email_dict = {
        row[0]: dict(zip(COLS, row)) for row in csv.reader(infile)
    }

smtp = smtplib.SMTP('localhost:587')
smtp.starttls()
smtp.login(…)

for filename in os.listdir(PATH):
    rep_id = re.split('[_.]', filename)[1]
    rep = email_dict.get(rep_id)
    if rep is None:
        continue
    msg = message_for(os.path.join(PATH, filename), *rep)
    smtp.sendmail('me', rep['email'], msg.as_string())
    print("Sent %s to %s" % (filename, rep['email']))

smtp.quit()
```

Comment: I appreciate the input.  I am trying to figure out how to work in the StingIO(), but am having some difficulty.  Also, thank you for the hints.  I appreciate the help as I work on my skills.

Answer (score 2):

Your first block, reading the csv can be changed in two ways.

1. You change `EmailDict = dict()` to `email_dict = {}`.
   It's uncommon to do `dict()` unless there is a requirement, like type conversion.
   Also Python uses `snake_case` for variables.
2. You can change the block to just use a dictionary comprehension.
   It's simple to setup and voids my above comment.

   All it is is syntatic suger over what you have to increas readability.

   ```
   with open('commissionrepemaillist.csv', 'r') as infile:
       reader = csv.reader(infile)
       email_dict = {
           row[0]: row[1], row[2]
           for row in reader
       }
   ```

   While it removes the information about what the different items are,
   it makes reading much faster. And you code to look nicer.

---

You can use another dictionary comprehension to generate `file_dict`.
I personally have never come across `re.split("[_.]", FILE)`, but it's an neet idea!

```
    file_dict = {
        re.split("[_.]", file_name)[1]: file_name
        for file_name in os.listdir(path)
    }
```

---

You normally want to loop through the smaller dictionary.
I assume that the folder has more, if not lots more, files than you wish to send in the email.

This is as the check `if ID in EmailDict:` is \$O(1)\$ not \$O(e)\$, where as `for ID in FileDict` is \$O(f)\$.
If we get the time it takes to loop through either it will be \$O(e \times 1)\$ for `EmailDict`,
and \$O(f \times 1)\$ for `FileDict`. And so you want to pick the smaller of the two.

However, it's unlikely that it will have *too much* of an impact, and so you may ignore this if you wish.

You can use `dict.iteritems()` to iterate through both the ID and the file name.
There is a subtle difference between `dict.items` and `dict.iteritems`,
the latter is in most cases better, and so became the default in Python3.
It's usage is:

```
for ID, file_name in file_dict.iteritems():
    if ID in email_dict:
        ...
```

You redefine `path` in each enumeration to the same static path.
This hinders execution time a little, and is not productive.

Also `file` is python keyword, and so it's *highly* advised against re-assigning it.
This is as from that point on, as you redefined it in the global scope,
if you wish to use it you will have to use `__builtin__.file`, which is definitely not good. I would use `file_path` instead.

The rest of the block, apart from `else: continue`, seems good.

---

Last block now.

There seems to be a bug(?) or an intention to send all files, even un-encrypted ones,
to the *last* person in the csv...

`EMAIL` is only defined in the first block, or with my changes not at all.
And due to the lack of check for `if ID in email_dict`,
it means that even un-encrypted files will be sent,
as only files with the ID in both `email_dict` and `file_dict` will be encrypted.

Other than the same problems that were highlighted in the other blocks.
I would assume that you don't have to create a new smtp connection for each email.
Instead I would move the all bar `s.sendmail(...)` out of the loop.

---

## Higher level stuff:

- I would do both the encryption and the email in the same loop.
  However I would encourage the use of a function, to make the logic easier to read.
- Use 'raw raw string'. A raw string in Python is `"Hello world"`,
  a 'raw raw string' has an r in-front of it, and prevents character escaping.
  For example `r'\n'` is `'\\n'`.
- Stop over-writing path, you're making more work for when you change the path!
  Or want to use this script in a different place.
- I think over-writing the files is a bad idea, instead I would make a new file,
  which would be something like `file_name + '_cypt'`.
- It's generally better to use `str.format` over `%`. This is as `%` has quirks.
- As this is a real world application, you would want to only execute if it's the main program.
  This is just a small security feature.

  ```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
      ...
  ```

---

And so I would re-write your program to the following:

```
import os 
import re
import csv
import PyPDF2
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText 
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

PATH = r"C:\Apps\CorVu\DATA\Reports\Monthly Commission Reports\Output\pdcom1"

def encrypt(file_path, password):
    input_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file_path)
    output = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
    output.appendPagesFromReader(inputStream)
    output.encrypt(password)

    with open(file, 'wb') as outputStream:
        # Is this a bug? Should it not be the other way around?
        output.write(outputStream)  

def send_email(file_path, email, ID):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as pdf :
        pdf = MIMEApplication(pdf.read(), _subtype = 'pdf')
        pdf.add_header(
            'content-disposition',
            'attachment',
            filename=('MonthlyPaidCommission_{}.pdf'.format(ID)))

        text = MIMEText(
            """For Rep Number : {} 
            Please use the password previously emailed to open attached file.
            If you have any questions or need assistance please contact  me.
            Thank you""".format(ID))

    msg = MIMEMultipart(_subparts=(text, pdf))
    msg['SUBJECT'] = "Commission Report"
    msg['FROM'] = "me@gmail.com"
    msg['TO'] = email

    s = smtplib.SMTP("LOCALHOST:587")
    s.starttls()
    s.login('user', 'pwd')
    s.sendmail('me@123.com', email, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('commissionrepemaillist.csv', 'r') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        emails = {
            row[0]: row[1], row[2]
            for row in reader
        }

    files = {
        re.split('[_.]', file_name)[1]
        for file_name in os.listdir(path)
    }

    for ID, email_info in emails:
        if ID in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(PATH + files[ID])
            encrypt(file_path, email_info[1])
            send_email(file_path, email_info[0], ID)
```

Comment: thank you SO much for your feedback.  I will definitely make the improvements.  Also I dont think the outputStream is a bug, as I'm overwriting the original file with the encrypted file (output).

Comment: @AlliDeacon I've never used `PyPDF2`, so the only reason I thought it was a bug is as it's _normally_ the other way around in Python. E.g. `outputStream.write(output)`.